# Difference between the community.vmware and "normal" vmware modules in Ansible?

Tags: module, ansible, vmware

What is the difference between the module [`community.vmware.vmware_content`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_content_deploy_template_module.html#ansible-collections-community-vmware-vmware-content-deploy-template-module) from the `community.vmware` collection
and the one advised on this page: [Deploy a virtual machine from a template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/vmware_scenarios/scenario_clone_template.html), are they Ansible core modules?

And which is recommended to use?

Comment: `vmware_guest` is actually the "short" name of the fully qualified name [`community.vmware.vmware_guest`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_guest_module.html), so they are both coming from the same community collection.

Comment: But in the requirements for 'community.vmware.vmware_guest' is 'vSphere Automation SDK' python extension needed. In  "vmware_guest" not. So it seems to work different!?

Comment: @EduardoSaverin, I assume that developers move forward to abstract the logic via company SDK's and call them from Python modules, rather than implementing the logic self in modules.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which Ansible version you are. [As modules move from the core Ansible repository into collections, the module documentation will move to the collections pages](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/collections_using.html).

> ... are they Ansible core plugins?

In newer Ansible versions, above v2.9 they are not longer. See [Where did all the modules go?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#where-did-all-the-modules-go)

The second link you reference ("*Deploy a virtual machine from a template*") is from the [Scenario Guides](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/vmware_scenarios/scenario_clone_template.html) and not a module documentation.

Comment: Im using: Ansible 4.8.with ansible-core 2.11.6. I heard from the split of the collection-modules and core-modules. But the  "vmware_guest funktion", described in the Scenario Guides needs less reqirements than the community.vmware.vmware_guest doku (vSphere Automation SDK). So from my understanding it should be a different module!?

Comment: @EduardoSaverin, regarding "_"vmware_guest function", described in the Scenario Guides_", it might be that that part of the documentation has not been updated yet. Regarding "_than the community.vmware.vmware_guest_", that would indicate that the module in question is still in Ansible Core, which it shouldn't according your version, as well that are two streams of concurrent module versions developed which will do almost the same.

Comment: I mean, why should this be so unlikely? Even if there is a second modules that did the same. Wouldn't be the first time that code gets forked because it's (my be) obsolete or does not offer the desired functions. Dont get me wrong, thanks for your answers. I just wnat to know whats going on and what i should use. :-D

Comment: @EduardoSaverin, regarding "_why should this be so unlikely?_" maybe the FAQ [Where did all the modules go?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html) gives a better explanation. I understand that article that modules for virtualization environments are not basic features and functions.

Comment: Ok, yes it does. Thanks for your time!